# What would the pitfalls (if any) be of re-instantiating an instance on the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'd rather not get into the why I might want to do this, but more of if I should/shouldn't and what the caveats for doing so would be. In case the title isn't clear on the intention:

There is an instance of an object on the stage with class MyClass and the instance name MyObject. In the document class:

```
public var myObject:MyClass;

public function init():void
{
    myObject = new MyClass();
    addChild(myObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only pitfall I see would be if you instantiate too many of them without removing them from the display list and/or memory.

Instantiating a class and putting it on the stage is a perfectly logical way to do things, even if you already intantiated it through Flash' UI.

I would just correct your syntax (case and ;):

```
public var myObject:MyClass;

public function init():void
{
    myObject = new MyClass();
    addChild(myObject);
}
```

Comment: Haha @ the case and semi-colons.. to be honest I typed the question with MyObject and was too lazy to fix it so I kept it. Edited now though. Thanks Kodiak I appreciate the answer. I only plan on re-instantiating or reassigning it once.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no pitfalls to this since you are assigning a new instance of the class to `myObject`. This will be enough for the Garbage Collector to be able to reclaim whatever resources were taken up by the instance created by the Flash IDE.

Comment: And that was my initial concern; Garbage Collection and event listeners. Basically the idea is to allow the object to be visible and positioned in the IDE and then reassign the variable and pass parameters to the constructor.